# Flutter: programmatically cause darkTheme to be used

Tags: flutter, android-dark-theme

In Flutter, you can set a dark theme to be used, which will be used if certain contexts (e.g. Dark Mode is set on Android Q). Is there a recommended way to allow that to be overridden  programmatically; e.g, in response to a user preference?

I guess this could be done at the very top level of the app:

```
MaterialApp(
    theme: ThemeData.light(),
    darkTheme: ThemeData.dark(),
    themeMode: fromSomeState,
)
```

However, I'd also like to be able switch on whether or not the app is in dark mode programmatically at various points in the app (e.g. for image selection):

```
MediaQuery.of(context).platformBrightness == Brightness.dark;
```

I could try and update the `MediaQueryData` to override `platformBrightness` as well, but that can only be done inside `MaterialApp`, which seems awkward.

Is there a better pattern for doing this kind of thing?

Answer (score 2):

You can check out [dynamic_theme](https://pub.dev/packages/dynamic_theme#-installing-tab-)

**How to use**

Just add `Dynamic Theme` as the parent of your `MaterialApp`

```
DynamicTheme(
  defaultBrightness: Brightness.light,
  data: (brightness) => new ThemeData(
    primarySwatch: Colors.indigo,
    brightness: brightness,
  ),
  themedWidgetBuilder: (context, theme) {
    return new MaterialApp(
        .......
    );
  }
)
```

Get the `currentBrightness` using

```
    DynamicTheme.of(context).brightness;
```

And Set it using

```
    DynamicTheme.of(context).setBrightness(Theme.of(context).brightness == Brightness.dark? Brightness.light: Brightness.dark);
```

You can read more about it or create your own, check this medium [Post](https://proandroiddev.com/how-to-dynamically-change-the-theme-in-flutter-698bd022d0f0)

**Edited**

You can check the current OS theme using

```
MediaQuery.of(context).platformBrightness;
```

And set the theme accordingly.

Comment: Looks handy, although I guess there's still an issue about how you detect that dark mode has been requested by the OS if the user hasn't specified a firm preference.

Comment: You can check the current OS theme and set it accordingly, see the edited part.

Comment: Isn't there a bit of a chicken-and-egg here? if you want to use `MediaQuery` to set  `DynamicTheme.defaultBrightness`, you need to be inside a `MaterialApp`, but that's built inside `DynamicTheme`... 

Comment: Yeah but What if we make MaterialApp parent of Dynamic Theme?